# Problem with table names in excel with oledb driver 

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

I am using Oledb driver to load data from excel for displaying in tabcontrol with datargids

I am using following loop to load data from every sheet

```
foreach (string str in sheets)
                {

                    string query = "SELECT * FROM [" + str + "]";


                    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = query;
                    adapter.Fill(ds,str);
                }
```

It works well until sheet names start with numbers. I have a excel file whose sheet name is `26203 REV C (EVK)`. It throws me error as `The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object ''26203 REV C [EVK]$'_'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.`What can be the remedy to the problem. I do not have any control over the sheet names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using backticks (`) instead of brackets:

```
SELECT * FROM `26203 REV C (EVK)$`
```

Remember that you also need to include the dollar symbol suffix when selecting.